# MIN and MAX for a year from datetime using linq to sql

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

How can I perform this MS SQL Query with Linq to SQL in C#

```
SELECT DATEPART(yy, MAX (articleDate)) AS max_year,
DATEPART(yy, MIN (articleDate)) AS min_year
FROM News;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do it in a single query easily/elegantly, but otherwise it's straightforward:

```
var minYear = dbContext.News.Min(x => x.ArticleDate.Year);
var maxYear = dbContext.News.Max(x => x.ArticleDate.Year);
```

(There *may* be a way of doing it within a single query, but only by adding some sort of wrapper query as far as I can think.)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
var foo = (from article in context.New
          group article.ArticleDate.Year by 1 into g
          select new
                     {
                         MinResult = g.Min(),
                         MaxResult = g.Max()
                     }).FirstOrDefault();
```